# .htaccess Redirect non-WWW to WWW preserving URI string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I'm running the CodeIgniter platform, which uses .htaccess to accept URLs like

```
http://www.mysite.com/controller/function/argument
```

I currently use some .htaccess rewrites, namely (simplified):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/images|/assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to add a rewrite rule that redirects all non www requests to www. I also want the URI string following the domain name to stay the same in the redirect. For instance, if a user makes a request for `http://mysite.com/controller/function/argument`, I want the .htaccess file to rewrite the request in the browser as `http://www.mysite.com/controller/function/argument` and then process the request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This won't interfere with my second RewriteRule right? I understand your RewriteCond, I don't want to apply to the rules I already have.

Comment: If you add mine as the first one, it will only be activated if the host is not www.mysite.com. If it is activated, there will be a redirect HTTP, and the second HTTP query will activate your own rewrite if the conditions are met

Comment: @Steven Xu, RewriteConds only apply to the next immediate RewriteRule.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem, and this .htaccess works for me

```
RewriteEngine On                           

#This bit rewrites your host name to include www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#This bit does the codeigniter magic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it's working. What if I want to add rule except blog.example.com is not redirected to www?

Comment: try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|blog)\.example\.com [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on apache 2.4 ,You can use the following simple redirect :

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} =='example.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</if>
```