# apache url rewrite with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess, and I'd like to rewrite my domain.com to www.domain.com. How can i do this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|xml|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string

Comment: True. The 2nd one was good for me. Thanks. (I haven't find it earlier.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great solution, unfortunately I already known this, but it's not working with my rewrite.

I need all the links to go to the index file. Like: `http://www.domain.com/oinon` and `http://www.domain.com/whatdoyoulike/elephants` all opens the `root/index.php`

Comment: @marharépa, if you use this condition and rule before your index rewrite, it should do exactly that.