# codeigniter redirect non-www to www

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i saw [.htaccess Redirect non-WWW to WWW preserving URI string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string) but it doesn't work for me

if i go to **mysite.com/site/something** i get redirected to **mysite.com/something**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

**edit:**

here's the code im using, based on Alfonso Rubalcava's answer:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 3) != 'www')
{

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '//site/')
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: http://www.site.com/site/');
        exit;
    }

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://www.site.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: This `//site/` looks like a malformed link. You may wish to correct in the code (in a view?) To avoid the search engines will index it as such.

Comment: oh..the link is not malformed, must be something with CI routes or htaccess to remove the index.php..the behavior is the same when i type the address on the browser

Comment: `http://www.site.com//site/`?

Comment: i thought you meant that i made the link wrong

Comment: better use`header("Location: http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` for making it dynamic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try, in index.php, at the beginning:

```
if(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,3)=="www"){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://yourdomain.tdl/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else{
    //the current contents of your file
}
```

**EDIT**
I read your question wrong, the answer is:

```
if(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,3)!="www"){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.tdl/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else{
    //the current contents of your file
}
```

Comment: can't i do this only using htaccess?

Comment: Yes, you can. This is just one way to do it with something more familiar and less problematic... and that will not require adjustment every time you migrate from server.

Comment: thanks, it works..btw i removed the "else" statement and used a "exit;" at the end of the if :]

Comment: oh..only problem is if i go to "mysite.com/site" i get redirected to "mysite.com//site" and i get a 404 error..

Comment: Remove the `/` from `yourdomain.tdl/".$_SERVER[` I'm glad it was useful.

Comment: hm i already did that, this only happens when i got to the /site

Comment: i solved by redirecting to the full path when it hits: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '//site/')

Comment: Hi, I try the solution but got `The page isn't redirecting properly`. What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 4):

include these two lines in the .htaccess file of codeigniter to redirect non-www url to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i.e the full .htaccess file will be something like that->

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
#Redirect to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, the problem already has an accepted solution. But there is a problem if the domain has also some subdomains. If your codeigniter handles subdomains too, the subdomains will be redirected to www too.

Here is the answer in this case. Let's say that your domain is www.thedomain.com, the code should be:

```
$sna = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
if($sna[0]=="thedomain"){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.thedomain.com/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code in all codeigniter website.

`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`