# htaccess redirect non-www to www the full path

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, no-www

I would like to redirect `example.com/test` to `www.example.com/test` and `example.com/contact` to `www.example.com/contact`.

So with all the routes of the web.
Everything I find, what it does is redirect `example.com/test` to `www.example.com`

Below is my code, and with all that I have tried it happens to me the same. They work fine, but they don't do what I want.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please, any suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Redirect non-WWW to WWW preserving URI string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add www prefix to url is easy, please try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this help. And you may want to visit this link to know more 
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/adding-or-removing-the-www-prefix-in-domain-urls

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD I**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

**METHOD II**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

You can use either of these two. The only difference between two is `%{SERVER_NAME}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not searched properly:

http://techstream.org/Web-Development/HTACCESS/WWW-to-Non-WWW-and-Non-WWW-to-WWW-redirect-with-HTACCESS